# problema al renderizar una foto en un componente

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un problema a la hora de renderizar una foto en react

```
export default class Media extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {subTitle: props.subTitle }
}

componentWillMount(){
   console.log(this.props.img)
}

HandlerClick = (event) =>{
    this.setState({subTitle: 'click'})
   // this.forceUpdate();
   console.log('dd')

}

render(){
    return(

        <div className="Media" onClick={this.HandlerClick } >
            <div className="Media-cover" >
                <img
                    src={this.props.img}
                    alt=''
                    width={260}
                    height={160}
                    className="Media-image"
                />
                <h3 className="Media-title" >{this.props.title}</h3>
                <p className="Media-author" >{this.state.subTitle}</p>
                </div>                    
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

como pueden ver en la etiqueta  le paso en el atributo src la ubicacion
de la imagen en mis archivos, pero luego en el navegador simplemente no se muestra, a modo de prueba agregue un import con la dirección de una de las fotos y en ese caso si se muestra:

```
import foto from "./Images/covers/responsive.jpg"
```

pero obviamente eso no me sirve por que necesito usar el componte en diferentes casos con deferentes imágenes.
ahora les dejo el componente padre por si influye en algo

```
export default class Playlist extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}
```

render(){

```
return(
    <div>
        {this.props.src.categories[0].playlist.map( (item) => {
            return <Media title={item.title} subTitle={item.author} img={item.cover} key={item.id} />
        }) }
    </div>
    )}
```

}

la pregunta es como puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Cuando le das console.log(this.props.img), que te muestra?

Comment: ./Images/covers/responsive.jpg que es la dirección donde se encuentran la imágenes

Comment: Otra pregunta, las imagenes que pasaras son dinamicas, la ruta tambien cambia? o siempre estaran en ./Images/covers/?

Comment: no, se encuentran siempre en la misma ruta

Comment: creo que ya pude detectar el causante del problema, es que eso se ejecuta en el navegador, por ende esa dirección no es valida en ese contexto, ahora el problema es que no se donde se compila todo el código de react, hay alguna forma de saber cual es el archivo de la app que se ejecuta en el navegador? (yo no hice la configuración de la app la descargue de https://www.reactboilerplate.com/ creo que esta echa con node.js )